# What is a good program to check CPU properties?

Tags: cpu

My computer is running an AMD Phenom II quad core CPU but it didn't come with the piece of software that I see people have in a lot of YouTube videos. The software is kind of like the ATI Catalyst Control center but for the AMD processor instead.

It shows things like current core temperature, clock speed, etc., but maybe it also allows the user to make changes to those things from the control center as well.

What is that software called?

Comment: can you post a link to a YouTube video which shows it?

Answer (score 5):

In the past, I've used [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) to see a lot of information about the processor, memory and other devices.

[image: CPU-Z]

Answer (score 2):

[CoreTemp](http://www.alcpu.com/CoreTemp/) maybe? [SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) perhaps?

[image]

[image]

Comment: +1 for SpeedFan -- That's what I would have suggested

Answer (score 0):

[Real Temp](http://www.techpowerup.com/realtemp/) is a great program for both temperature sensing and quick burn tests.

> Real Temp is a temperature monitoring program designed for all Intel single Core, Dual Core, Quad Core and Core i7 processors. Each core on these processors has a digital thermal sensor (DTS) that reports temperature data relative to TJMax which is the safe maximum operating core temperature for the CPU.

[image]